# Funcionamento do Gradle Scripts

Tags: android

Já li vários tópicos a respeito do funcionamento 'retrocompatibilidade' do Android e suas versões, inclusive a documentação do mesmo. Mas continuo sem entender uma coisa: 


Eu garanto que meu aplicativo funcionará por completo em uma versão anterior, API 19 - Android KitKat por exemplo, apenas especificando minha         `minSdkVersion` como 19 no `build.gradle(Module:app)`?


E quanto ao `buildToolsVersion` e `compileSdkVersion`, qual a diferença dos dois? Li no StackOverflow Norte Americano uma explicação, e mesmo assim não ficou muito claro pra mim. Alguém poderia clarear as ideias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, com `minSdkVersion` você garante parte da retrocompatibilidade. Vou explicar mais adiante o porque só parte dela.

Respondendo de forma rápida a primeira pergunta, sim, não só com o `minSdkVersion` sendo 19, mas qualquer valor menor ou igual ao 19 você garante compatibilidade com o KitKat.

---

Explicando alguns nomes levantados:

## `buildToolsVersion`

O `buildToolsVersion` é a versão das ferramentas de *build*, algumas são: `aapt` (que processa os recursos e gera a classe `R`), o `aidl` (que processa suas interfaces de serviços), o `dx` (que pega os *bytecodes*  e gera o *dex*), o `zipalign` (que alinha os recursos para 4 bytes de endereçamento) e mais recentes o `jack` e o `jill`. O valor do `buildToolsVersion` é quase independente das versões do SDK.

`Jack and jill` na teoria vieram a um tempo atrás pra substituir o `aapt`, o `dx` e o `zipalign` e o `proguard`, tornando o processo de build em apenas uma ou duas etapas. Isso pode ser visto mais em detalhes [aqui](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill). Eles funcionam, mas não atendem alguns casos em que a o uso de *annotation processing*, que em geral é quem usa o *AndroidAnnotations* ou *Dagger2* e outros...

## `compileSdkVersion`

O `compileSdkVersion` é a versão que você vai compilar o código. Você pode compilar usando a versão 23, mas ter o `minSdkVersion` sendo 14. Isso não há problema.

Uma configuração normal é que o `targetSdkVersion` seja igual ao `compileSdkVersion` mas que você escolha um valor razoável para o `minSdkVersion`. A escolha do `minSdkVersion` em geral deve se levar em conta a porcentagem de aparelhos no mercado com uma determinada versão e as dificuldades técnicas de se usar aquela versão.
Nessa linha, é sempre bom consultar o [Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) com os dados de utilização das versões.

## `targetSdkVersion`

Tome um certo cuidado com o `targetSdkVersion`, porque algumas versões tem comportamento diferente se você utilizar um valor de `targetSdkVersion` igual a versão do dispositivo. Isso pode ser visto com mais detalhes no release notes de cada versão.

O segundo ponto sobre compatibilidade que é o mais importante. É muito comum utilizarmos o `targetSdkVersion` e o `compileSdkVersion` sendo a versão mais recente, 23 nesse momento. Isso é legal, mas temos que tomar muito cuidado com as API's que estamos usando, porque se estamos utilizando algo que não esteja disponível na `minSdkVersion` que foi definido, irá dar crash em tempo de execução (vulgo `NoSuchMethodException`) ou então possui um comportamento diferente do esperado ou então está "descontinuado" em versões mais novas.

Para esses casos, o `lint` nos alerta durante o desenvolvimento e durante o build. Mas é bom sempre se certificar antes de utilizar.

Comment: Era justamente isso que eu gostaria de saber Wakim! O meu medo era se ocorreria algum tipo de erro caso o meu minSdkVersion fosse uma versão anterior, 19 por exemplo, e eu usasse mesmo assim alguns recursos mais novos, que vieram depois dessa minSdk. Mas pelo sua explicação e pelo que li sobre as 'Support Libraries' tudo faz sentido. Obrigado!